# Having trouble to insert local image into the seeds.rb file in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am tring to insert an image in my `assets` directory into my `seeds.rb` file by using the following code: (I found this code online)

```
Product.destroy_all

p1=Product.create! name: "Peachy Oolong", price:15.00, stock:50, description: "Dong Ding Oolong Tea with Shizuoka , we call it the best combo for ice cream. "
 p1.avatar.attach(io: File.open(Rails.root.join('app/assets/images/peach.JPG')),filename: 'peach.JPG')
```

On the console, it shows the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `avatar' for #<Product:0x000000013a508210>
/Users/dizhang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activemodel-5.2.6/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:430:in `method_missing'
```

How do I fix this NoMethodError?

Comment: The information is a bit lacking. Does the avatar field exist in your Product model?

Comment: You didn't define avatar field in your product class.